# Cache response data in NextJS API route

Tags: next.js, caching

I have an API route in NextJS that :

1. Fetch some news data from a third parti (using “fetch“)
2. Make some call to google translate to transform the resulting data (also some fetch).
3. return the translated data

My issue is that in each request, the server calls google-translate c and it may take a while. The response doesn't change often since the news are updated only monthly.
Is there a way to cache the response for further request.

I tried this:

```
 res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, s-maxage=3600, stale-while-revalidate=59"
  );
```

But the response time is not much better (according to my tests).

Do you have any Idea on how to proceed to set up a proper cache with a given lifetime?

Here's how my query looks like (`in the file` /pages/api/anything`):

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
)
  //fetch
  try {
    const post = await fetch("https://gatenine.ch/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>
        data.map((item: any) =>
          _.pick(
            item,
            "yoast_head_json",
            "title",
            "description",
            "modified",
            "content"
          )
        )
      );
    console.log(post);
    try {
      //parse and translate
      const newPost = await Promise.all(
        post.map(async (element: any) => {
          const fr = await translate(
            [element.title.rendered, element.content.rendered],
            {
              from: "de",
              to: "fr",
            }
          )
            .then((data: any) => {
              return data;
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
              console.log(err);
              return null;
            });
          var nO = element;
          if (fr != null) {
            nO = _.extend(element, { frTitle: fr[0] }, { frContent: fr[1] });
          } else {
            nO = _.extend(
              element,
              { frTitle: element.title.rendered },
              { frContent: element.content.rendered }
            );
          }
          return nO;
        })
      );
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "news successfully retrieved", data: newPost });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("failed during transalation");
      console.log(e);
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "news successfully retrieved", data: post });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed during fetch");
    res.status(500);
  }
}
```

I would like to cache the result of this request-

Comment: can you check network tab if browser is making a new request?

Comment: I used Postman to query the api. From what you said I guess it's cached in the client's browser... Is it possible to have it cached in the NextJS app so that any user benefits from it?

Answer (score 0):

For nextjs v14, requests made with fetch api are cached by default. Subsequent api calls use the cached data. So you can utilise that and then revalidate as and when you need new data. you can [read here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch).

More so, use react-query or similar libraries which can allow you to cache response data

Comment: My code is an api request, so I cannot use react-query since it has to be used in a react component. And I need a caching of the response of my api route, which does several calls to other api, which may have different signature (so the default cache system of "fetch" does not really help.

Answer (score 0):

**Nextjs 14** with **App Router** Solution.

I am using this Response with Cache-Control to cache the API result on Vercel (CDN):

```
  return Response.json(response, {
    status: 200,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=60, immutable',
    }),
  })
```

[image]